# creating new view in iPhone application

Tags: iphone

i just finished my first view in my iPhone app and i want to add a second view to wich the user go when he click in the button in the first view. So i add new view from the librairy window, but i don't see the battery in the top, is that normal ? and how to add it please ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean the status bar along the top you can try this code to make sure it is shown:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
```

or:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
```

if you want to animate it coming down.

Cheers.

Comment: THX a lot, but please where should i put it ??

Comment: That's a little difficult to answer without seeing your code but putting it in either the init function of your 2nd view or, better yet, the ViewDidLoad or ViewWillAppear methods should do the trick.